# Safely changing innodb_buffer_pool_size on MySQL replication master?

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mysql-5.5, ubuntu

We have a MySQL server which is a replication master. We need to change the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_flush_method` to (hopefully) improve performance as the database has grown.

What is the "safest" method for us to do this? We have 2 slave servers which will need to continue replication after this is done.

The plan so far is:

1. Stop replication on the 2 slave servers with `STOP SLAVE`.
2. Stop MySQL on all 3 servers with `service mysql stop`.
3. Make the changes in the `my.cnf` file on the ***master*** server.
4. Start MySQL on the ***master*** again to get the live database back online ASAP with `service mysql start`.
5. Make the changes in the `my.cnf` file in both the ***slave*** servers.
6. Start MySQL again on both ***slave*** servers with `service mysql start`.

The settings are:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 54G
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

The server has 64GB of memory and is a dedicated MySQL server, the server doesn't really do anything else at all. It's a `Dell PowerEdge R720` running `Ubuntu 12.04 Server`.

Can anyone foresee any problems with this method? Is there anything else we need to be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have seems fine. I would add the following

Run this on the Master.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
SET GLOBAL sync_binlog = 1;
SET GLOBAL sync_master_info = 1;
```

This will cause everything that has been uncommitted to be committed on shutdown.

Then, it flushes the binlogs to disk.

On the Slaves, run this

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
SET GLOBAL sync_binlog = 1;
SET GLOBAL sync_relay_log = 1;
SET GLOBAL sync_relay_log-info = 1;
SET GLOBAL sync_master_info = 1;
```

This will flush all the binlogs and relay logs. If the Slaves do not have binary logging enabled, then skip `SET GLOBAL sync_binlog = 1;`.

Your steps look like this now:

1. Stop replication on the 2 slave servers with STOP SLAVE.
2. Run `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;` on all three servers
3. Run `SET GLOBAL sync_binlog = 1;` on the Master
4. Run `SET GLOBAL sync_master_info = 1; SET GLOBAL sync_relay_log = 1; SET GLOBAL sync_relay_log-info = 1; SET GLOBAL sync_master_info = 1;` on the Slave
5. Stop MySQL on all 3 servers with `service mysql stop`.
6. Make the changes in the `my.cnf` file on the master server.
7. Start MySQL on the master again to get the live database back online ASAP with `service mysql start`.
8. Make the changes in the my.cnf file in both the slave servers.
9. Start MySQL again on both slave servers with `service mysql start`.

Comment: Finally managed to schedule the time for this last night. Seemed to go well. All changed and no issues found so far! There was a minor typo in your SET GLOBAL commands, "sync_relay_log-info" should have been "sync_relay_log_info" (which it won't let me edit in your post because I didn't change at least 6 characters), but that was easily corrected. Thanks for your help/input!

Comment: Found this answer useful so made the edit to fix the "sync_relay_log-info" typo. Got around the 6 character limit by adding some punctuation. :D